# HTML Materialize CSS Dropdown and SideNav not working in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, materialize

I am helping my friend to create a replica of scholarship portal for college project. I made the navbar using materialize css and gave the html and css file to my friend to integrate it with angular. Me and my friend both are absolute beginners at angular and the dropdowns & sidenav does not respond upon clicking. Saw many solutions on the internet but we are unable to solve it.

Putting my html code of the navbar below

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}

*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   
}

.dropdown-content{
    width: max-content !important;
    height:auto !important;
 }

 .nav-wrapper{
    background-color:white;
 }

 .material-icons{
    color: #EBA63F;
 }

 #logo-nav{
    color: #E40C2B;
    width: 100%;
 }

 .li-nav{
    color: #3CBCC3;
 }

 .li-nav:hover{
    color:#1D1D2C;
 }

 #sidenav1{
    color: #1D1D2C;
    background-color: #F7F4E9;
 }

 #sidenav1:hover{
    background-color:#EBA63F;
    color: #1D1D2C;
 }

 #dropdown-css{
    color: #1D1D2C;
 }

 #dropdown-css:hover{
    background-color: #EBA63F;
 }

 #sidenav1>.material-icons{
    color: #1D1D2C;
 }

 .sidenav{
    background-color: #F7F4E9;
 }

 .logos{
   margin-top: 20px;
   background-color: #3CBCC3;
 }

 
 @media only screen and (max-width: 810px) {
    div.nav-wrapper {
       /* height: 15vh;*/
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -3px #000;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -3px #000;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -3px #000;
    }
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 560px) {
    #logo-nav{
      font-size: medium;
    }
}

  .logo,.logo1{
    height: 40px
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Courier+Prime&family=Noto+Sans&family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   
    <!--jquery-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <!--bootstrap-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--materialize css-->
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <!--materialize css icons-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--font awesome-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
    <!--bootstrap font awesome cdn-->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

   
    <!--css-->
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar2.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css"/>
    
    <title>Navbar Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<!--navbar ends here-->
  <!-- Dropdown Structure for navbar -->

  <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a id="dropdown-css" href="#!">Student Login</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a id="dropdown-css" href="#!">Institute Login</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a id="dropdown-css" href="#!">Ministry Login</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a id="dropdown-css" href="#!">Nodal Officer Login</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Dropdown Structure for navbar -->
  <ul id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a id="dropdown-css" href="#!">Student Register</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a id="dropdown-css" href="#!">Institute Register</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a id="dropdown-css" href="#!">Ministry Register</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a id="dropdown-css" href="#!">Nodal Officer Register</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Dropdown Structure for sidenav bar -->
    <ul id="dropdown3" class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a id="sidenav1" href="#!">Student Login</a></li>
        <li><a id="sidenav1" href="#!">Institute Login</a></li>
        <li><a id="sidenav1" href="#!">Ministry Login</a></li>
        <li><a id="sidenav1" href="#!">Nodal Officer Login</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Dropdown Structure for sidenav bar -->
    <ul id="dropdown4" class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a id="sidenav1" href="#!">Student Register</a></li>
        <li><a id="sidenav1" href="#!">Institute Register</a></li>
        <li><a id="sidenav1" href="#!">Ministry Register</a></li>
        <li><a id="sidenav1" href="#!">Nodal Officer Register</a></li>
      </ul>

  
  <!-- Navbar main code starts here -->
  <nav>
    
    <a href="#" class="sidenav-trigger" data-target="mobile-demo"><i class="material-icons" >menu</i></a>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a class="li-nav" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>    
                <div class="center row">
                   <div class="col s12 " >
                     <div class="row" id="topbarsearch">
                       <div class="input-field col s6 s12">
                         <i class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
                         <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete li-nav" >
                         </div>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>          
               </li>
        </ul>
      
      <ul class="right hide-on-small-only">
        
        <!-- login and register navbar Dropdown Trigger -->
        <li><a class="dropdown-trigger li-nav" href="#!" data-target="dropdown1">Login<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-trigger li-nav" href="#!" data-target="dropdown2">Register<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="li-nav" href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a class="li-nav" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!--sidenav main code-->
    <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li><a id="sidenav1 show-on-large" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a id="sidenav1" class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown3">Login<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
        <li><a id="sidenav1" class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown4">Register<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
        <li><a id="sidenav1" href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a id="sidenav1" href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a id="logo-nav" href="#!" class="brand-logo center">National Scholarship Portal</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<!--navbar ends here-->

  <script>  
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown({inDuration: 300, outDuration: 100, coverTrigger: false, alignment: 'center',});
        $('.sidenav').sidenav();
        //$('.button-collapse').sideNav();
        $('.parallax').parallax();
     });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It would mean everything to me if anyone can give me code for angular
I only included snippet of navbar above
This is my entire page that I made: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QSifk0BneW3i_OKIU0RYcMRFusZ78q-k?usp=sharing

Please Please help me run this code in Angular

Comment: I just did more digging and found that script tags are removed by angular. I am totally clueless of what to do now... If anyone can help please reach out on my email: pal.riya.18it2040@gmail.com or on my telegram/instagram @palriya292 (username same for both platforms)

Comment: Have You tried using [MATERIAL ANGULAR](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)  or you just wanna do it in plain css and html

Comment: @Rohit_29 I have never used material angular... this is all plain html, css, js scripts using materialize css

Comment: I am suggesting you to use that it will make your code simpler and efficient